# How to use helpers in handlebars with webpack(handlebars-loader)

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am using Handlebars in my project and bundling templates using webpack. I am using `handlebars-loader` to compile templates. I got issue  when I created a small helper. Webpack shows this error when I use helper in my template:

```
You specified knownHelpersOnly, but used the unknown helper withCurrentItem - 5:4
```

This is my code:

**Webapck:**

```
{
        test   : /\.(tpl|hbs)$/,
        loader : "handlebars-loader?helperDirs[]=" + __dirname + "templates/helpers"
        // use    : 'handlebars-loader?helperDirs[]=false' + __dirname + 'templates/helpers'
},
```

**Helper(project/templates/helpers/withCurrentItem.js):**

```
export default function (context, options) {
  const contextWithCurrentItem = context

  contextWithCurrentItem.currentItem = options.hash.currentItem

  return options.fn(contextWithCurrentItem)
}
```

**Template file(project/templates/products.tpl):**

```
{{> partials/filters}}
<ul class="u-4-5">
  {{#each data.products}}
    {{> partials/product}}
    {{withCurrentItem ../styles currentItem=this}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I tried to resolve the problem and searched over the internet but I couldn't find any thing. This is what I have tried to:

- Add `helperDirs[]` query param to loader as:

  loader : "handlebars-loader?helperDirs[]=" + __dirname + "templates/helpers"
- Add helpers directory path to `resolve.modules` property of webpack config file

Sadly, none of them work.

Answer (score 8):

For me, none of these approaches worked. I used `runtime` option to create my own instance of Handlebars (thanks to this [comment](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader/issues/110#issuecomment-401445723)):

webpack.config.js

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(handlebars|hbs)$/,
      loader: 'handlebars-loader',
      options: {
        runtime: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/handlebars'),
      },
    },
```

path/to/handlebars.js

```js
const Handlebars = require('handlebars/runtime');
Handlebars.registerHelper('loud', function(aString) {
  return aString.toUpperCase();
});
module.exports = Handlebars;
```

Answer (score 6):

**webpack@3.5.5** and **handlebars-loader@1.5.0**:

```
{
  test: /\.hbs$/,
  loader: 'handlebars-loader',
  options: {
    helperDirs: path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/helpers'),
    precompileOptions: {
      knownHelpersOnly: false,
    },
  },
},
```

Update 2021: also works with **webpack@4+**.

Comment: Is there any way to register helpers without separate files for them in native hbs way (handlebars.registerhelper(args)) in webpack.config? Also how to register helpers from npm modules(handlebars-layouts, handlebars-helpers)?

Comment: If you're using webpack, you should avoid using inline helper (native hbs registerHelper), it's inconsistent. For other question, try to use `config.helperResolver` configuration for `handlebars-loader`

Answer (score 1):

Following config worked for me in webpack 4

```
// webpack
{
    test: /\.hbs$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'handlebars-loader?runtime=handlebars/runtime',
        options: {
            precompileOptions: {
                knownHelpersOnly: false,
            }
        }
    }]
}


// helpers/ifEq.js
module.exports = function (a, b, opts) {
    if (a === b) {
        return opts.fn(this);
    }
    return opts.inverse(this);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of helpers? I am doing exact same things but still helpers are not loading.

Comment: @PushkarKathuria Updated configuration